# jQuery losing div wrap, + problems with modifying elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a form, where user can ADD or REMOVE rows dynamically. I have built jQuery Functions to accomplish this however I am losing some elements in the process and I can't figure out why.

**HTML Snippet**

```
<div class="options" id="options">
        <div class="item1" id="item1">
            <div class="left_wrap">
                <ul>
                    <li class="col_id b-bottom"></li>
                    <li class="hazard_header"><h3>Hazard</h3></li>
                    <li class="hazard_input b-bottom"></li>
                    <li class="con_header b-bottom"><h3>Controls</h3></li>
                    <li class="cat_header"><h3>Consequence Category</h3></li>
                    <li class="cat_options"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right_wrap">
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="addRow" onclick="addRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Row</div>
                <div class="deleteRow" onclick="deleteRow('#item1')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete Row</div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
    </div> <!-- End Options Wrap -->
```

***jQuery***

```
var count = 1;
var wrap;
var item;

function addRow(){
    count++;
    var $newElement = $(item);
        $newElement.find("li.col_id").text(count);
        // Doesn't work
        $newElement.find(".item1").removeClass("item1").addClass("item"+count);
        // Remove ID item1 make it (item+count)
        // Change deleteRow('#item1') to deleteRow('#item2')
        $($newElement).appendTo(".options");

    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    wrap = $(".options").html();
    item = wrap;
    id = $("div.item1");
    id.find("li.col_id").text("1");
});
```

I have commented out parts inside the addRow that I am having problems with. Wired thing is when I display my (item) inside .ready it shows me wrap () however when I do it inside addRow it doesn't show it anymore.

I have been stuck on this for few hours and have tried few different ways to do this however I keep coming up short.

When I click Add Row it does work however I can never change the class and id for the wrap.

Comment: make a http://jsfiddle.net/ , bro

Comment: Try `wrap = $(".options");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your Code.
$newElement is already the main DIV that you want to update with new ID and Class.

```js
var count = 1;
var wrap;
var item;

function addRow(){
    count++;
    var $newElement = $(item);
        $newElement.find("li.col_id").text(count);
        // Remove previous class and Add new Class
        $newElement.attr('class','').addClass("item"+count);
        // Update the ID
        $newElement.attr('id',"item"+count);
        // Update the onlick event with new Item ID
        $newElement.find('.deleteRow').attr('onclick','deleteRow("#'+"item"+count+'")');
        // Remove ID item1 make it (item+count)
        // Change deleteRow('#item1') to deleteRow('#item2')
        $($newElement).appendTo(".options");

    };

$(document).ready(function(){
    wrap = $(".options").html();
    item = wrap;
    id = $("div.item1");
    id.find("li.col_id").text("1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options" id="options">
        <div class="item1" id="item1">
            <div class="left_wrap">
                <ul>
                    <li class="col_id b-bottom"></li>
                    <li class="hazard_header"><h3>Hazard</h3></li>
                    <li class="hazard_input b-bottom"></li>
                    <li class="con_header b-bottom"><h3>Controls</h3></li>
                    <li class="cat_header"><h3>Consequence Category</h3></li>
                    <li class="cat_options"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right_wrap">
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="addRow" onclick="addRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Row</div>
                <div class="deleteRow" onclick="deleteRow('#item1')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete Row</div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- End Item -->
    </div> <!-- End Options Wrap -->
```

Comment: Works perfect, so I was making a mistake by using .find instead of attribute ( I assume).. Thanks  you!

Comment: @theStudent Yes, that's the only mistake.